# NULL == pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++,we usually check a pointer whether is null or not, I just know we should use

```
if(NULL == ptr)
```

instead of:

```
if(ptr == NULL)
```

I want to know why?

In additiol, if we want to initialized a ptr to null,should we use `ptr = NULL` or `ptr = 0`? yes I know in C++, we usually use `ptr = nullptr`, I want to know why shall we do like this just want to unify the code ? thanks

Comment: I usually write `if (!ptr)`. It is shorter and less redundant.

Comment: I'm little confuse here, whether your question is why can't you use `NULL==ptr` instead of `ptr==NULL` or your question is why can't you use `=` instead of `==` ?

Comment: I asked two questions

Comment: Its called a [Yoda Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a coding style (named [Yoda Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions)) to avoid writing `=` instead of `==` in an if-statement, it's valid to use assignment `=` in an if-statement, but it's usually not what you want.

Personally, I prefer not to use like this because it's hard to read and modern compilers will warn you when you use `=` in an if-statement.

Also note that:

1. `if(ptr == NULL)` is the same with `if(!ptr)`.
2. C++11 introduced `nullptr` to replace using `NULL`. So to initialize a null pointer, it's preferred to use `ptr = nullptr`

About why use `nullptr` over `NULL`:

Before C++11, `NULL` is usually implemented internally as `#define NULL 0`, but the problem is, `0` is also the integer zero. It may cause trouble in some situations. For example:

```
void func(int n);   
void func(char *s);

func(NULL);   //call which function?
```

Though the auther implies that `NULL` is a pointer type, but the compiler just know  to call `func(0)`. So the first version will be called.

Using `func(nullptr)`, the compiler will know it's a pointer and call the second version.

Comment: +1, but I would point out that the problem is that `=` is *assignment* even in a conditional - this often confuses beginners. This is always assumed in this answer, but never stated explicitly.

Comment: It’s `nullptr`, not `null_ptr`.

Comment: yes in my second question, I know we should use nullptr, I want to know why? just want to unify the code style?

Comment: @minicaptain You mean you don't understand why use `nullptr` over `NULL` or why to initialize a pointer to null pointer?

Comment: I want to know why use nullptr ove null,thanks!

Comment: @minicaptain `nullptr` was introduced for better type safety. For example, given two functions `void foo(int i)` and `void foo(char* str)`, then the call `foo(NULL)` is not valid in C++ because it's ambiguous. Even though you know that want to call the `foo(char*)` overload, the compiler can't know that. On the other hand, `foo(nullptr)` is perfectly fine, since `nullptr` is only valid a parameter to `foo(char*)` and not `foo(int)`.

Comment: As to modern compilers spotting that mistake - this is not true - sometimes they miss it!

Answer (score 1):

Using yoda equality it prevents certain mistakes such as using a single `=` or where the compiler tries to determine an integer from a smart pointer.

It has been known

I spent two days tracking down that error as they think yoda is a bad idea.